# Python Project Euler digit fifth powers

Tags: python, loops, sum, project, digit

[Here is the problem](https://projecteuler.net/problem=30):

> Surprisingly there are only three numbers that can be written as the
>   sum of fourth powers of their digits:
>
> 1634 = 1^4 + 6^4 + 3^4 + 4^4
>      8208 = 8^4 + 2^4 + 0^4 + 8^4
>      9474 = 9^4 + 4^4 + 7^4 + 4^4
>
> As 1 = 1^4 is not a sum it is not included.
>
> The sum of these numbers is 1634 + 8208 + 9474 = 19316.
>
> Find the sum of all the numbers that can be written as the sum of
>   fifth powers of their digits.

And here is my code:

```
summ = 0
digit_sum = 0
i = 0
while i < 1000000:
    j = list(str(i))
    for x in j:
       digit = int(x) ** 5
       digit_sum += digit
    if digit_sum == i:
       summ += i
       print(i)
    else:
       digit_sum = 0
    i += 1
print(summ)
```

Can anyone find out that why I miss a value 4151 which should be one of the correct answer?

Comment: I suggest using a debugger or add `print` statements to your code to figure out what it is doing. You can add an `if` statement to only print when the loop reaches 4151.

Answer (score 2):

The problem in your code is you forgot to reset the `digit_sum` when you got an answer.
Put `digit_sum = 0` before `j = list(str(i))`. You also start with `i = 0`. I suggest to start with `i = 10` since the first 2 digit number is 10.

use this:

```
[i for i in range(10, 1000000) if i == sum(int(d) ** 5 for d in str(i))]
```

equivalent with:

```
[4150, 4151, 54748, 92727, 93084, 194979]
```

using sum:

```
sum(i for i in range(10, 1000000) if i == sum(int(d) ** 5 for d in str(i)))
```

equivalent with:

```
443839
```

Comment: 1 isn't included.  Should be `range(2, 100000)`.  Correct answer is 443839.

Comment: maybe `range(10, 1000000)` if no single digit number accepted.

Comment: The upper limit of the range only needs to be `sum(int(d)**5 for d in "9"*5)`, or `295245`

Answer (score 1):

4150 is also in solutions. The digit_sum is not set to 0 before 4151 step. You should set digit_sum = 0 in each step.

```
summ = 0
i = 10
while i < 1000000:
    digit_sum = 0
    j = list(str(i))
    for x in j:
        digit = int(x) ** 5
        digit_sum += digit
    if digit_sum == i:
        summ += i
        print(i)
    i += 1

print(summ)
```

Comment: Also on the edit starting from 10 removes 1 as in the problem definition, 1 is left out.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is that you don't reset `digit_sum` every time, only when `digit_sum != i`.  If you remove the `else` statement, it should work correctly.

```
if digit_sum == i:
   summ += i
   print(i)
digit_sum = 0
i += 1
```